# Pausing animation at timed intervals in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have a couple classes:

```
public class Project
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Session> ScrollSessions { get; set; }
    public int ScrollLength { get; set; }
    public Duration ScrollDuration { get; set; }
}
public class Session
{
    //FullText contains multiple lines of text:
    public string FullText { get; set; }
}
```

I have an ItemsControl that will be dynamically populated with custom Buttons bound to an ObservableCollection of Projects. Each button will have a TextBlock at the top that displays the Project.Code. The rest of the button is filled with a Canvas that contains another ItemsControl with a horizontal StackPanel ItemsPanelTemplate. This second ItemsControl will be dynamically populated with TextBlocks bound to the ObservableCollection of Sessions for each Project.

If Sessions only has one element there will be no animation, but if it has more than one, I want the TextBlocks to scroll right to left as a Marquis, pausing briefly for each one in a continuous loop. I've gotten to the point where I can get them to scroll continuously following the second answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929344/continuous-text-ticker-in-wpf). I started by copying Sessions into ScrollSessions and then adding a second copy of the first Session to the end of it. I bound the DoubleAnimation To property to ScrollLength and the Duration Property to ScrollDuration.

xaml as best as I can remember when I had this much working:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Margin="4,64,10,78">
<ItemsControl x:Name="projectItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource ProjectButtonStyle}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="baseIconLargeDouble.png"/>
                </Button.Background>
                <DockPanel Style="{DynamicResource ProjectDockPanelStyle}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectCode}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <Canvas>
                        <ItemsControl Margin="0,3,0,18" ItemsSource="{Binding ScrollSessionSettings}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullText}" Style="{DynamicResource SessionTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="0" To="{Binding Scroll}" FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <!--<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static local:PlantLauncher.StartEvent}">
                                    <PauseStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Animation"/>
                                </EventTrigger>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static local:PlantLauncher.StopEvent}">
                                    <ResumeStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Animation"/>
                                </EventTrigger>-->
                            </ItemsControl.Triggers>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Canvas>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I say as best as I can remember since I went off on a boondoggle of creating all this stuff in code behind and it still didn't work. I am new to WPF and have trouble especially with linking the xaml with the code behind.

So my question is how can I make this animation pause at timed intervals? Can I do it completely in xaml, or do I need a code behind Timer? I even tried a custom RoutedEvent but the event wasn't getting marked as handled (you can see it commented out in the xaml above)... There has got to be an easy way to do this.